# Imagens auto-redimensionaveis com JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, android, imagem

Estou usando o exemplo clássico de `listview` presente na [documentação](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/listview/#&ui-state=dialog) do `jquery mobile`. Porem, ao usar imagens com tamanhos diferentes, gostaria que a imagem automaticamente ficasse do tamanho do `container`, como fazer isso?